# Why is the realm property of a RealmSwift.List nil?

Tags: ios, swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I have been following the following Realm tutorial:

[Tutorial: Build iOS App from Scratch](https://realm.io/docs/tutorials/realmtasks/)

The app is running, the `ROS` instance as well, but when I add a new task, it doesn't get saved. I have zeroed-in and found that in `add()`, the write portion of the code doesn't get executed:

```
let items = self.items
try! items.realm?.write {
    items.insert(Task(value: ["text": text]), at: items.filter("completed = false").count)
}
```

`self.realm` looks like this:

```
(lldb) p self.realm
(RealmSwift.Realm?) $R0 = 0x000061800022ff60 {
  rlmRealm = 0x00006000000bdd00 {
    ObjectiveC.NSObject = {
      isa = RLMRealm
    }
  }
}
```

`items` looks like this:

```
(lldb) p items
(RealmSwift.List<RealmDemo.Task>) $R1 = 0x0000600000026fa0 {
  RealmSwift.ListBase = {
    Realm.RLMListBase = {
      baseNSObject@0 = {
        isa = 0x0000600000026fa0
      }
      __rlmArray = 0x000061000004ee20
    }
  }
}
```

`items.realm` looks like this:

```
(lldb) p items.realm
(RealmSwift.Realm?) $R2 = nil
```

That explains why the `write` op doesn't get executed. What am I missing? I have verified the code and looks the same as in the tutorial (except for the credentials, of course).

Any ideas?

Comment: That tutorial requires that you've run one of the RealmTasks sample apps at least once with the same object server, so that `items.realm` isn't nil.

Comment: Ah! Cool. It now works. It would be great if the page (https://realm.io/docs/tutorials/realmtasks/) mentioned that it's a pre-requisite to run the tutorial. Thanks JP!